# Need explanation after "git clean -df" deleted all the files on my computer

Tags: git, file

I am very new to git, and recently started tracking a couple of files. After fiddling around, I decided I wanted to stop tracking the files and clear them from my working directory.

I looked up the command for clearing the working directory, and came back with "git clean -df". Long story short, ended up clearing my entire MacBook of all its files. It seems like these are not recoverable, but can someone explain in simple terms why this happened? I was unaware that the working directory automatically included all the files on my computer, I thought it was only files I had manually decided to add.

Comment: _"I was unaware that the working directory automatically included all the files on my computer"_ It doesn't

Comment: `git clean` removes untracked files from the working directory. It does not remove files that have been committed. To do that you would use `git rm`.  So if your git repo is at the root of your hard drive, then running `git clean -df` would remove all the files from your disk that aren't committed.

Comment: "if your git repo is at the root of your hard drive" what exactly does this mean?

Comment: In future, is it considered good practice to not have my git repo at the root of my HD?

Comment: Yes, your git repository should be placed where you naturally would work with the files in the workspace.  This is typically somewhere in your home folder.  Regarding the lost files - the MacOS installation procedure can restore your computer completely from your latest time machine backup.  I bought a Time Capsule solely for this capability.

Comment: To make this happen you had to either wipe ownership on every file in the system first or aimlessly fire up a root shell to play with a tool you don't understand.